# Can we integrate Azure Form Recognizer Studio interface directly into our application?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

As I know Form Recognizer Studio is an online tool for visually exploring, understanding, and integrating features from the Form Recognizer service into your applications. But can we integrate studio tool directly into our web application for visualisation, training and testing?

I tried to check on microsoft forums but didn't get exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not integrate Form Recognizer tool into your webapplication, but You can use the Form Recognizer models into your web application using the C#, Java, JavaScript, or Python client libraries or the REST API.